# Windows Phone maps detect leaving route

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I was wondering if there was something in the Windows Phone Maps API that could help me detect when i leave my route. I need this to be able to do the route calculation again.

If there isn't something in the api is there any other way i could get what i want?